# Take text From the filter textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have enabled filtering in my `RadGrid` as follows

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="gvSample" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server"
        GridLines="None" CellSpacing="1" Skin="WebBlue" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="50"
        AllowFilteringByColumn="true">
```

In the Item command I need to get the value entered in the filter textbox in the second column. How can I get it? I had tried the following but it wont gives the actual output?

```
Private Sub gvSample_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As elerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles gvSample.ItemCommand
    lblMsg_.Text=gvSample.FilterMenu.Items(1).Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, put in the question what you where expecting too see in lblMsg and what you are getting with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code explains it

```
Private Sub gvSample_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) 
    If e.CommandName = RadGrid.FilterCommandName Then           
            lblMsg_.Text = gvSample.MasterTableView.GetColumn(col[1].UniqueName).CurrentFilterValue.ToString()          
    End If
End Sub
```

Reference can be reached [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-get-filterfunction-filtervalue-from-code-behind)

Also, you can reach more details and sample code in both C# and VB.NET from Telerik site itself 
[Here is the demo for filtering](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/filtering/basic-filtering/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true)

**Updated:**
Make sure you set AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" in your markup